# How can I write a JPA query without native query that includes join operation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

So I have a SQL query like this,

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM USERS.NAMES UN
  JOIN USERS.ADDRESS UA
    ON ADDRESS_TYPE IN ('{user_supplied_value_1}', '{user_supplied_value_2}')
   AND UN.USERS_ID = UA.USERS_ID
 WHERE UN.NAMES_ID = '{user_supplied_value}'
```

How can I write a derived JPA query for this without having to use a native query?

I was thinking of something along the lines of this,

`List<Names> findAllByNamesIdAndAddressTypeIn`

Comment: That query returns everything in both `NAMES` and `ADDRESS`. Which one do you actually need? Also, please share your `@Entities`, as those determine whether or not JPA performs a `JOIN`. As a final note, I **believe** that `IN` is not supported by JPA, but it is in JPQL. Let me check on that

Comment: Double-checked, `IN` is supported in JPA as well.